# Adding a new object to the model returns 'list' object has no attribute '_committed' error

Tags: django, django-models

I want to add a new object to the model in database but when I tried to add it, it gives an error like 'list' object has no attribute '_committed'

It gives an error at the part of **car_model.save()**

**Traceback Error**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars/add_car

Django Version: 3.1.7
Python Version: 3.9.0
Installed Applications:
['cars.apps.CarsConfig',
 'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
 'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
 'contact.apps.ContactConfig',
 'houses.apps.HousesConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'ckeditor',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.sites']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gx760_000\Desktop\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\gx760_000\Desktop\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gx760_000\Desktop\sahibinden\cars\views.py", line 434, in add_car
    car_model.save()
  File "C:\Users\gx760_000\Desktop\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\gx760_000\Desktop\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 790, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\gx760_000\Desktop\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 895, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "C:\Users\gx760_000\Desktop\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 933, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "C:\Users\gx760_000\Desktop\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\gx760_000\Desktop\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1254, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\gx760_000\Desktop\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1396, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "C:\Users\gx760_000\Desktop\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1339, in as_sql
    value_rows = [
  File "C:\Users\gx760_000\Desktop\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1340, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\gx760_000\Desktop\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1340, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\gx760_000\Desktop\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1291, in pre_save_val
    return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
  File "C:\Users\gx760_000\Desktop\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 305, in pre_save
    if file and not file._committed:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /cars/add_car
Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

**views.py**

```
def add_car(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES:
        user_id = request.POST['user_id']
        brand = request.POST['brand']
        status_of_car = request.POST['status_of_car']
        city = request.POST['city']
        ilce = request.POST['ilce']
        e_mail = request.POST['e_mail']
        phone_number = request.POST['phone_number']
        car_title = request.POST['car_title']
        description = request.POST['description']
        price = request.POST['price']
        serial = request.POST['serial']
        color = request.POST['color']
        model = request.POST['model']
        year = request.POST['year']
        condition = request.POST['condition']
        body_style = request.POST['body_style']
        engine = request.POST['engine']
        transmission = request.POST['transmission']
        interior = request.POST['interior']
        kilometers = request.POST['kilometers']
        passengers = request.POST['passengers']
        power_of_engine = request.POST['power_of_engine']
        fuel_type = request.POST['fuel_type']
        no_of_owners = request.POST['no_of_owners']
        car_photo = request.FILES.getlist('car_photo')
        car_photo_1 = request.FILES.getlist('car_photo_1')
        car_photo_2 = request.FILES.getlist('car_photo_2')
        car_photo_3 = request.FILES.getlist('car_photo_3')
        car_photo_4 = request.FILES.getlist('car_photo_4')
        car_photo_5 = request.FILES.getlist('car_photo_5')
        car_photo_6 = request.FILES.getlist('car_photo_6')
        car_photo_7 = request.FILES.getlist('car_photo_7')
        car_photo_8 = request.FILES.getlist('car_photo_8')
        car_photo_9 = request.FILES.getlist('car_photo_9')
        car_photo_10 = request.FILES.getlist('car_photo_10')
        car_photo_11 = request.FILES.getlist('car_photo_11')
        car_photo_12 = request.FILES.getlist('car_photo_12')
        car_photo_13 = request.FILES.getlist('car_photo_13')
        car_photo_14 = request.FILES.getlist('car_photo_14')
        feature_1 = request.POST.get('feature_1')
        feature_2 = request.POST.get('feature_2')
        feature_3 = request.POST.get('feature_3')
        feature_4 = request.POST.get('feature_4')
        feature_5 = request.POST.get('feature_5')
        feature_6 = request.POST.get('feature_6')
        feature_7 = request.POST.get('feature_7')
        feature_8 = request.POST.get('feature_8')
        feature_9 = request.POST.get('feature_9')
        feature_10 = request.POST.get('feature_10')
        feature_11 = request.POST.get('feature_11')
        feature_12 = request.POST.get('feature_12')
        feature_13 = request.POST.get('feature_13')
        feature_14 = request.POST.get('feature_14')
        feature_15 = request.POST.get('feature_15')
        feature_16 = request.POST.get('feature_16')
        feature_17 = request.POST.get('feature_17')
        feature_18 = request.POST.get('feature_18')
        feature_19 = request.POST.get('feature_19')
        feature_20 = request.POST.get('feature_20')
        feature_21 = request.POST.get('feature_21')
        feature_22 = request.POST.get('feature_22')
        feature_23 = request.POST.get('feature_23')
        feature_24 = request.POST.get('feature_24')
        feature_25 = request.POST.get('feature_25')
        feature_26 = request.POST.get('feature_26')
        feature_27 = request.POST.get('feature_27')
        feature_28 = request.POST.get('feature_28')
        feature_29 = request.POST.get('feature_29')
        feature_30 = request.POST.get('feature_30')
        feature_31 = request.POST.get('feature_31')
        feature_32 = request.POST.get('feature_32')
        hardware_feature_1 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_1')
        hardware_feature_2 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_2')
        hardware_feature_3 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_3')
        hardware_feature_4 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_4')
        hardware_feature_5 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_5')
        hardware_feature_6 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_6')
        hardware_feature_7 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_7')
        hardware_feature_8 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_8')
        hardware_feature_9 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_9')
        hardware_feature_10 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_10')
        hardware_feature_11 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_11')
        hardware_feature_12 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_12')
        hardware_feature_13 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_13')
        hardware_feature_14 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_14')
        hardware_feature_15 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_15')
        hardware_feature_16 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_16')
        hardware_feature_17 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_17')
        hardware_feature_18 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_18')
        hardware_feature_19 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_19')
        hardware_feature_20 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_20')
        hardware_feature_21 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_21')
        hardware_feature_22 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_22')
        hardware_feature_23 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_23')
        hardware_feature_24 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_24')
        hardware_feature_25 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_25')
        hardware_feature_26 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_26')
        hardware_feature_27 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_27')
        hardware_feature_28 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_28')
        hardware_feature_29 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_29')
        hardware_feature_30 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_30')
        hardware_feature_31 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_31')
        hardware_feature_32 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_32')
        hardware_feature_33 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_33')
        hardware_feature_34 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_34')
        hardware_feature_35 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_35')
        hardware_feature_36 = request.POST.get('hardware_feature_36')
        ex_hardware_feature_1 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_1')
        ex_hardware_feature_2 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_2')
        ex_hardware_feature_3 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_3')
        ex_hardware_feature_4 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_4')
        ex_hardware_feature_5 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_5')
        ex_hardware_feature_6 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_6')
        ex_hardware_feature_7 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_7')
        ex_hardware_feature_8 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_8')
        ex_hardware_feature_9 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_9')
        ex_hardware_feature_10 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_10')
        ex_hardware_feature_11 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_11')
        ex_hardware_feature_12 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_12')
        ex_hardware_feature_13 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_13')
        ex_hardware_feature_14 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_14')
        ex_hardware_feature_15 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_15')
        ex_hardware_feature_16 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_16')
        ex_hardware_feature_17 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_17')
        ex_hardware_feature_18 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_18')
        ex_hardware_feature_19 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_19')
        ex_hardware_feature_20 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_20')
        ex_hardware_feature_21 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_21')
        ex_hardware_feature_22 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_22')
        ex_hardware_feature_23 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_23')
        ex_hardware_feature_24 = request.POST.get('ex_hardware_feature_24')
        multimedia_feature_1 = request.POST.get('multimedia_feature_1')
        multimedia_feature_2 = request.POST.get('multimedia_feature_2')
        multimedia_feature_3 = request.POST.get('multimedia_feature_3')
        multimedia_feature_4 = request.POST.get('multimedia_feature_4')
        multimedia_feature_5 = request.POST.get('multimedia_feature_5')
        multimedia_feature_6 = request.POST.get('multimedia_feature_6')
        multimedia_feature_7 = request.POST.get('multimedia_feature_7')
        multimedia_feature_8 = request.POST.get('multimedia_feature_8')
        multimedia_feature_9 = request.POST.get('multimedia_feature_9')
        multimedia_feature_10 = request.POST.get('multimedia_feature_10')
        multimedia_feature_11 = request.POST.get('multimedia_feature_11')
        multimedia_feature_12 = request.POST.get('multimedia_feature_12')
        multimedia_feature_13 = request.POST.get('multimedia_feature_13')
        is_featured = request.POST.get('is_featured')

        car_model = Car(user_id=user_id,
                        brand=brand,
                        status_of_car=status_of_car,
                        city=city,
                        ilce=ilce,
                        e_mail=e_mail,
                        phone_number=phone_number,
                        car_title=car_title,
                        description=description,
                        price=price,
                        serial=serial,
                        color=color,
                        model=model,
                        year=year,
                        condition=condition,
                        body_style=body_style,
                        engine=engine,
                        transmission=transmission,
                        interior=interior,
                        kilometers=kilometers,
                        passengers=passengers,
                        power_of_engine=power_of_engine,
                        fuel_type=fuel_type,
                        no_of_owners=no_of_owners,
                        car_photo=car_photo,
                        car_photo_1=car_photo_1,
                        car_photo_2=car_photo_2,
                        car_photo_3=car_photo_3,
                        car_photo_4=car_photo_4,
                        car_photo_5=car_photo_5,
                        car_photo_6=car_photo_6,
                        car_photo_7=car_photo_7,
                        car_photo_8=car_photo_8,
                        car_photo_9=car_photo_9,
                        car_photo_10=car_photo_10,
                        car_photo_11=car_photo_11,
                        car_photo_12=car_photo_12,
                        car_photo_13=car_photo_13,
                        car_photo_14=car_photo_14,
                        feature_1=feature_1,
                        feature_2=feature_2,
                        feature_3=feature_3,
                        feature_4=feature_4,
                        feature_5=feature_5,
                        feature_6=feature_6,
                        feature_7=feature_7,
                        feature_8=feature_8,
                        feature_9=feature_9,
                        feature_10=feature_10,
                        feature_11=feature_11,
                        feature_12=feature_12,
                        feature_13=feature_13,
                        feature_14=feature_14,
                        feature_15=feature_15,
                        feature_16=feature_16,
                        feature_17=feature_17,
                        feature_18=feature_18,
                        feature_19=feature_19,
                        feature_20=feature_20,
                        feature_21=feature_21,
                        feature_22=feature_22,
                        feature_23=feature_23,
                        feature_24=feature_24,
                        feature_25=feature_25,
                        feature_26=feature_26,
                        feature_27=feature_27,
                        feature_28=feature_28,
                        feature_29=feature_29,
                        feature_30=feature_30,
                        feature_31=feature_31,
                        feature_32=feature_32,
                        hardware_feature_1=hardware_feature_1,
                        hardware_feature_2=hardware_feature_2,
                        hardware_feature_3=hardware_feature_3,
                        hardware_feature_4=hardware_feature_4,
                        hardware_feature_5=hardware_feature_5,
                        hardware_feature_6=hardware_feature_6,
                        hardware_feature_7=hardware_feature_7,
                        hardware_feature_8=hardware_feature_8,
                        hardware_feature_9=hardware_feature_9,
                        hardware_feature_10=hardware_feature_10,
                        hardware_feature_11=hardware_feature_11,
                        hardware_feature_12=hardware_feature_12,
                        hardware_feature_13=hardware_feature_13,
                        hardware_feature_14=hardware_feature_14,
                        hardware_feature_15=hardware_feature_15,
                        hardware_feature_16=hardware_feature_16,
                        hardware_feature_17=hardware_feature_17,
                        hardware_feature_18=hardware_feature_18,
                        hardware_feature_19=hardware_feature_19,
                        hardware_feature_20=hardware_feature_20,
                        hardware_feature_21=hardware_feature_21,
                        hardware_feature_22=hardware_feature_22,
                        hardware_feature_23=hardware_feature_23,
                        hardware_feature_24=hardware_feature_24,
                        hardware_feature_25=hardware_feature_25,
                        hardware_feature_26=hardware_feature_26,
                        hardware_feature_27=hardware_feature_27,
                        hardware_feature_28=hardware_feature_28,
                        hardware_feature_29=hardware_feature_29,
                        hardware_feature_30=hardware_feature_30,
                        hardware_feature_31=hardware_feature_31,
                        hardware_feature_32=hardware_feature_32,
                        hardware_feature_33=hardware_feature_33,
                        hardware_feature_34=hardware_feature_34,
                        hardware_feature_35=hardware_feature_35,
                        hardware_feature_36=hardware_feature_36,
                        ex_hardware_feature_1=ex_hardware_feature_1,
                        ex_hardware_feature_2=ex_hardware_feature_2,
                        ex_hardware_feature_3=ex_hardware_feature_3,
                        ex_hardware_feature_4=ex_hardware_feature_4,
                        ex_hardware_feature_5=ex_hardware_feature_5,
                        ex_hardware_feature_6=ex_hardware_feature_6,
                        ex_hardware_feature_7=ex_hardware_feature_7,
                        ex_hardware_feature_8=ex_hardware_feature_8,
                        ex_hardware_feature_9=ex_hardware_feature_9,
                        ex_hardware_feature_10=ex_hardware_feature_10,
                        ex_hardware_feature_11=ex_hardware_feature_11,
                        ex_hardware_feature_12=ex_hardware_feature_12,
                        ex_hardware_feature_13=ex_hardware_feature_13,
                        ex_hardware_feature_14=ex_hardware_feature_14,
                        ex_hardware_feature_15=ex_hardware_feature_15,
                        ex_hardware_feature_16=ex_hardware_feature_16,
                        ex_hardware_feature_17=ex_hardware_feature_17,
                        ex_hardware_feature_18=ex_hardware_feature_18,
                        ex_hardware_feature_19=ex_hardware_feature_19,
                        ex_hardware_feature_20=ex_hardware_feature_20,
                        ex_hardware_feature_21=ex_hardware_feature_21,
                        ex_hardware_feature_22=ex_hardware_feature_22,
                        ex_hardware_feature_23=ex_hardware_feature_23,
                        ex_hardware_feature_24=ex_hardware_feature_24,
                        multimedia_feature_1=multimedia_feature_1,
                        multimedia_feature_2=multimedia_feature_2,
                        multimedia_feature_3=multimedia_feature_3,
                        multimedia_feature_4=multimedia_feature_4,
                        multimedia_feature_5=multimedia_feature_5,
                        multimedia_feature_6=multimedia_feature_6,
                        multimedia_feature_7=multimedia_feature_7,
                        multimedia_feature_8=multimedia_feature_8,
                        multimedia_feature_9=multimedia_feature_9,
                        multimedia_feature_10=multimedia_feature_10,
                        multimedia_feature_11=multimedia_feature_11,
                        multimedia_feature_12=multimedia_feature_12,
                        multimedia_feature_13=multimedia_feature_13,
                        is_featured=is_featured,)

        car_model.save()

        return redirect('cars')
    return render(request, 'cars/add_car.html')
```

I didn't use forms because  of the multichoice fields. I need to do my code without forms. Where is my mistake here and how can i fix it without using forms ?

Comment: Are you overriding the Car model save method? if yes pls add the details

Comment: What do you mean with that

Comment: @RedAndBlack you have used `request.FILES.getlist` for all your file inputs, whereas a file field can only save one file.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks so much that solved my problem. I changed all the getlist to get so it solved the problem